# Titanium (iPhone) - Scrollableview

Tags: iphone, titanium

I have scrollableview with 20 images / Views.

can I display all images in infinite mode means at the end of all view it will start to display automatically from 1 image/ view.

One kind of Cycling of all images while swipe (First - last - First.....)

Answer (score 0):

http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html it will help you.

This sample project url link, catch it, it will solve your problem may be http://iosdevelopertips.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/CircularScrollView.zip